# How to fix the position of one model on the scene and avoiding it's overlap with my other model to be rendered in ARKit/ARcore using Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I want to play the animation on my AR scene at the corner of my screen.I want it to be fixed there throughout my project. I want to deploy my objects everywhere else on the screen but it should not overlap with my animation playing on the corner of my screen. But, I still want my animated model to be playing with the camera background without getting affected by my other object spawned. I want both my animated object and object to be rendered to be working in a single scene in Unity. Can anyone suggest how can it be done?

Comment: I m trying to do exactly that but I am using Vuforia instead. Please, post an answer to your problem if you got one.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question, Maybe the best option is using the 2D object inside the canvas. In this way, you always see this objects in the canvas and you can't interact with this object, but you can interact with the recognize plane.

But if you use a 3D model, the way to do this it's put your 3d model near the camera in the position that you need, remove the collider and after you can interact with the SLAM Plane.

if you refer to another thing or I'm wrong. tell me and we look for another solution to help you. this solution's a fast and simple solution.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I'm using a 3D object. The above method is not exactly working. Can you suggest any other methods? I tried playing around with bounds, but it didn't work either.